# Pivotcache problem using ado recordset into excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, pivot-table

I'm having a problem with runtime error 1004 at the last line.  I'm bringing in an access query into excel 2007.  I know the recordset is ok as I can see the fields and data.  Im not sure about the picotcache was created in the set ptCache line.  I see the application, but the index is 0.  Code is below...

```
Private Sub cmdPivotTables_Click()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wkbTo As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wksTo As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim str As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim ptCache As Excel.PivotCache

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    'to handle case where excel is not open
    On Error GoTo errhandler:
    Set appExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    'returns to default excel error handling
    On Error GoTo 0
    appExcel.Visible = True
    str = FilePathReports & "Reports SCU\SCCUExcelReports.xlsx"
    'tests if the workbook is open (using workbookopen functiion)
    If WorkbookIsOpen("SCCUExcelReports.xlsx", appExcel) Then
        Set wkbTo = appExcel.Workbooks("SCCUExcelReports.xlsx")
        wkbTo.Save
        'To ensure correct Ratios&Charts is used
        wkbTo.Close
    End If
    Set wkbTo = GetObject(str)
    wkbTo.Application.Visible = True
    wkbTo.Parent.Windows("SCCUExcelReports.xlsx").Visible = True

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    strSQL = "SELECT viewBalanceSheetType.AccountTypeCode AS Type, viewBalanceSheetType.AccountGroupName AS AccountGroup, " _
                & "viewBalanceSheetType.AccountSubGroupName As SubGroup, qryAmountIncludingAdjustment.BranchCode AS Branch, " _
                & "viewBalanceSheetType.AccountNumber, viewBalanceSheetType.AccountName, " _
                & "qryAmountIncludingAdjustment.Amount, qryAmountIncludingAdjustment.MonthEndDate " _
            & "FROM viewBalanceSheetType INNER JOIN qryAmountIncludingAdjustment ON " _
                & "viewBalanceSheetType.AccountID = qryAmountIncludingAdjustment.AccountID " _
            & "WHERE (qryAmountIncludingAdjustment.MonthEndDate = GetCurrent()) " _
            & "ORDER BY viewBalanceSheetType.AccountTypeSortOrder, viewBalanceSheetType.AccountGroupSortOrder, " _
                & "viewBalanceSheetType.AccountNumber;"
    rs.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

'    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryExcelReportsTrialBalancePT", dbOpenForwardOnly)

**'**********problem here
    Set ptCache = wkbTo.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal)
    Set wkbTo.PivotCaches("ptCache").Recordset = rs**
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Pivot Cache isn't name "ptCache", it's probably "PivotCache1" or something.  Either of these will work, the former being preferred.

```
Set ptCache.Recordset = rs

Set wkbTo.PivotCaches(1).Recordset = rs
```

Comment: HI Dick,

Unfortunately that didn't work.  The former version gave me the same error, using the wkbTo.PivotCaches(1) gave me the error subscript out of range.  That suggests that the previous line where the ptCache is created didn't work?

Comment: That would seem to be the case, but it should give you an error on that line.  I don't have 2007 handy, but in 2003 there is no Create method for PivotCaches, only an Add method.  If that's still true in 2007 and your suppressing errors around that line, then that would be the culprit.  In any event, I'll check it out in 2007 as soon as I can.

Comment: Hi Dick
That was one thing I found.  In excel 2007 there is no add method, but there is a create method which looks the same.  I had add at first and got error 438 (I think).
Also, I'm not suppressing errors.
And since my laast message, I have dumped the rs onto the spreadsheet no problem and created pivotcache and pivottable from that sheet.  But still really want to know how to create pivot table ado recordset.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works in Excel, but not from Access.  I don't know why.  Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish and maybe we can find a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just a thought.  I noticed you were declaring two `rs` variables (one using `ADODB` and one using `DAO`) in the same subroutine.  To be frank, I'm surprised the compiler didn't catch this for you, but I would suggest trying one or the other, but not both (and since you're initializing `rs` as `ADODB.RecordSet`, you should probably comment out `rs = DAO.RecordSet`).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this error rise because your 'strSQL' is too long; Run your code with simpler strSQLbut I don't know how solve for long strSQL.

Answer (score 0):

MHosseinput may have been onto something there. I have done this in excel many years ago and I notice that I split the sql into chunks and passed an array or arrays to the pivot object. Of course, there's no comment explaining why I did that and I don't remember any more, but it does work.

> ```
> Set oPivCache = oWb.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal) 
> oPivCache.Connection = "OLEDB;" & sConnStr
> oPivCache.CommandType = xlCmdSql oPivCache.CommandText = Array( _
>     Array(LEFT(sqry, 200)), _
>     Array(Mid(sqry, 201, 200)), _
>     Array(Mid(sqry, 401, 200)), _
>     Array(Mid(sqry, 601, 200)), _
>     Array(Mid(sqry, 801, 200)), _
>     Array(Mid(sqry, 1001, 200))) 
> oPivCache.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=oPVSht.Range("A1"), TableName:=sPvName
> ```